# iOS UIImageView - Top of Image Chopped Off?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, alignment

I'm new to iOS Development, I'm using a UIImageView to display an image. I've made a 320x480 and a 640x960 image called "red.png" and "red@2x.png".

No matter how I scale or align the UIImageView, the image always chops off half way at the top.

Is there something I'm meant to do to combat this, as I thought those resolutions were correct?

The UIImageView is sized at 320x568 to fill the storyboard.

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you could share some more details, including a screenshot of the problem, and maybe some code of the UIImageView or a screenshot of Interface Builder?

Comment: No problem :)

Screenshot of issue: http://postimg.org/image/8zs2khq41/
Screenshot of IB: http://postimg.org/image/ekc9pu03n/

Comment: Only related code is below, very basic:

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.colourImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"red@2x.png"];

Comment: Alan's answer below should do the trick. By the way, it's possible to edit your question; so you could've added the code or screenshots to it. By doing so, the problem would be more clear to other people reading your question (and not the comments below it).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll do that in future :) Unfortunately I accidentally misled Alan as I'd already tried his solution and the result is the same.

Comment: Can you NSLog(@"content mode is %d", myImageView.contentMode);.  It should probably be set to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.  In other words, myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: Maybe you could also make a screenshot in Interface Builder showing the [attributes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XKjP3.png) of the UIImageView?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see additional comments! I don't know how to NSLog, but the UIImageView is set to Aspect Fit. But the top third or so of the image is still chopped off, as if it's stretched vertically beyond the top edge.

Comment: Screenshot of attributes of UIImageView: http://postimg.org/image/4dz2azast/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to image name as follows:

```
self.colourImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"red.png"];
```

You should not directly specify `'@2x'` in image names.
It is automatically used if a device supports retina display.
That is why you need to create 2 sets of images; one for non-retina and one for retina (using @2x) and the OS selects the correct one for you.

Comment: Apologies, I had it set to "red.png", I was just trying @2x in the example above, but the result was exactly the same. :(

Comment: Still stuck with this, anyone any ideas please?

Comment: @darryls87 It is very difficult to guess what is wrong. Since this is very basic thing, I suggest you find an good tutorial using an ImageView and start from scratch and follow along.

Answer (score 0):

My comment above is hard to read, and it's probably an answer:

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: where do I put that, please?

Comment: I adapted it to self.ColourImage.contentMode. The image now displays further up the screen, leaving the background colour showing as a band at the bottom of the screen.